# Tensorflow Image Captioning tutorial - Decoder RNN state

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I have a little question about a tutorial that I've read in Tensorflow which is the image captioning tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning)

We can see in the following code block the usage of the GRU in the decoding stage where x is the attention context vector concatenated with the input.

```
    # passing the concatenated vector to the GRU
    output, state = self.gru(x)
```

I don't understand why we don't also pass the previous hidden state to the GRU. As we are decoding sequentially, we should give the previous hidden state to the actual GRU, am I wrong ? Maybe the implementation is doing it automatically ?

I'm coming from PyTorch where we feed the previous hidden state + the input to the current RNNCell.

Thanks in advance for your answer !